# Sci-fi story about a utopia about some technologically advanced people living in space stations and some on planets

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I read this sci-fi story at least 15 years ago. The story is about a far future utopia. There were two segments of people, technologically advanced  people living in stations or ships, and not so advanced ones living on planets. The station/ship people were living a life of 1000 years, the reproduction is completely controlled and in vitro, the concepts of family, parents, siblings and such are long lost their meaning.

Comment: I’ve edited out the second story as questions should be focused to one work. Please ask the second identification question as a new question. Also should you remember anything else about the story, plot wise, please [edit] your question to add in information.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What drove the plot, were there conflicts between the space-dwellers and the planet-dwellers?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97099/help-remembering-a-story-where-partial-stasis-is-taking-place

Answer (score 7):

The question thus far is extremely light on plot details, but the dichotomy between long-lived space-dwellers and short-lived (and technologically less-advanced) planet dwellers makes me think of [*Between the Strokes of Night*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2375) (1985) by Charles Sheffield.

It fits with the "hard SF" tag because there is no FTL in the universe; the space-dwellers' long life-spans is the only thing that enables a society to exist given the decades-long (or longer) time spans required for interstellar travel.

The novel opens with the initial expansion off of Earth and the investigation of hibernation as a means of surviving long space journeys.  This leads to the discovery of a stable metabolic state that allows the perception of time at an extremely slow rate, and a concomitant extension of lifespan.

The story then skips thousands of years into the future and to a planetary society where high-scoring individuals are recruited into the space-dwelling society.

You can read more details in the [plot synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_the_Strokes_of_Night) on Wikipedia.

Comment: "Between the Strokes of Night" was my initial thoughts but I don't recall invitro fertilisation being a major plot point?

Comment: @Alith In vitro _per se_ was not, but it _was_ a plot point that people living in the slow state couldn't have kids, so they needed another way to replenish their population.  I figured this was very close and worth proposing as an answer.

Comment: you're right, I'd forgotten that was one of the problems with the slow state :)